# Define custom touch area in custom UIControl object

Tags: ios, uicontrol

I am creating a custom UIControl object as detailed [here](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/how-to-build-a-custom-control-in-ios/). It is all working well except for the touch area.

I want to find a way to limit the touch area to only part of the control, in the example above I want it to be restricted to the black circumference only rather than the whole control area.

Any idea?
Cheers

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) (We're not here to do all the work - you need to have at least attempted to solve this yourself after reading the relevant documentation.)

Comment: I found this http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/ios-view-hit-regions/ that might accomplish what you are interested in doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override UIView's [`pointInside:withEvent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW2) to reject unwanted touches.

Here's a method that checks if the touch occurred in a ring around the center of the view:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];
    if (touch == nil)
        return NO;

    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;

    CGPoint center = { CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds) };
    CGVector delta = { touchPoint.x - center.x, touchPoint.y - center.y };
    CGFloat squareDistance = delta.dx * delta.dx + delta.dy * delta.dy;

    CGFloat outerRadius = bounds.size.width * 0.5;

    if (squareDistance > outerRadius * outerRadius)
        return NO;

    CGFloat innerRadius = outerRadius * 0.5;

    if (squareDistance < innerRadius * innerRadius)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

To detect other hits on more complex shapes you can use a `CGPath` to describe the shape and test using `CGPathContainsPoint`. Another way is to use an image of the control and test the pixel's alpha value.

All that depends on how you build your control.

Comment: I know about this but how do I detect the touch inside a particular shape drawn using core graphics. Again from the example I provided, how do I detect the intersection inside the black arc drawn in drawRect of the UIContrl?

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. This is more of a work around and I highly appreciate it. It is a good solution. But i want to know if there is any other way of detecting interaction with the content of the UIControl or not. In this example the area is simple, just a thick arc. But I invasion using areas of different polygonal shapes. Will there be a direct way to detect those?

Comment: @Abolfoooud Edited to reply.

Comment: "Another way is to use an image of the control and test the pixel's alpha value." this sounds like a good idea. i will give it a shot. Thanks