# Xcode How do you make circular hitboxes on buttons?

Tags: xcode, button

I'm using Xcode 5 to make an UIButton. I made the button in storyboard and set the background image to a .png of a circle with transparency. I set up a simple action for the button to display how many times it was pressed in a label.

When I press the corners of the circle on the screen, it still adds to the score. So the button is still keeping its square hitbox, even though it has a round image as its background. I searched everywhere for a way to make a circular hitbox, but I can't find anything. Is this even possible? Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: I know I should paste some code. But as this is something relatively complicated I'd like to forward you to check this site: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.de/2010/03/irregularly-shaped-uibuttons.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define custom touch area in custom UIControl object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073779/define-custom-touch-area-in-custom-uicontrol-object)

Answer (score -1):

The button responds to touch on corners because the bounding box of the button is a rectangle no matter what image you set for background.

To achieve a circular UIButton you must make a circular bounding box by simply using this code:

```
- (UIView *)setRoundedView:(UIView *)roundedView toDiameter:(float)newSize {
CGPoint saveCenter = roundedView.center;
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(roundedView.frame.origin.x, roundedView.frame.origin.y, newSize, newSize);
roundedView.frame = newFrame;
roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = newSize / 2.0;
roundedView.center = saveCenter;
roundedView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
return roundedView;
}
```

In this method you can pass any UIView or subclass of UIView in your case UIButton. So in code you must create an IBOutlet of you button and in your -viewDidLoad method simply put this line of code:

```
self.btnMyButton = (UIButton *)[self setRoundedView:self.profilePic toDiameter:34];
```

Assuming you UIButton outlet is btnMyButton and set the diameter as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Don't forget to import QuartzCore Framework.